# Retrieve index of nearest surface-points returned from CGAL's surface_neighbor_coordinates_3

Tags: indexing, interpolation, cgal, surface, triangulation

I (relatively new to CGAL and not a C++ expert) am trying to extract the *index* of the nearest-neighbor 3D points returned from CGAL's `surface_neighbor_coordinates_3` (which searches a 2D mesh comprised of 3D points to find natural-neighbors of a provided query-point) in [this CGAL example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Interpolation/Interpolation_2surface_neighbor_coordinates_3_8cpp-example.html).  In other examples (3D interpolation with 3D meshes), I have been able to do this by adding info to vertex handles in the triangulation data structure.  In the linked example, I simply wish to retrieve the indices of returned `coords` with respect to where the points in `coords` reside index-wise within the input list of `points`.

The [other call-options for `surface_neighbor_coordinates_3`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Interpolation/group__PkgInterpolationSurfaceNeighborCoordinates3.html#ga07c7f1c1efbbbe293fcb2835ca39ed0f) seem to suggest this may be possible by passing-in an existing triangulation (with perhaps its info-augmented triangulation-data-structure).  However, I'm not sure how to specify the info-augmented Delaunay_triangulation_3 for the case of a 2D mesh consisting of 3D points. I'm experimenting with it (using advancing-front triangulations to 2D-mesh my 3D points) but would like to know if there's some easier way to use the **native** capabilities of `surface_neighbor_coordinates_3` if one only seeks to also have an *info* field associated with the returned points.

Any help would be greatly appreciated ... this has stumped me for a week.

Comment: Can't you simply fill a map <Point_3, id> and query it after surface_neighbor _coordinates_3 ? Otherwise I fear you will have to create your own Traits class, defining a Point_3 type that contains an ID field.

Comment: @mgimeno: Thank you.  I wasn't familiar with `map`'s query capability (I have much to learn re: the various STL containers).  That gets me past my primary problem (being stuck).  As a now-less-significant issue, I'd like to avoid expensing a map-query for each returned coord point (by having the returned-iterator reference a more-general type of data than just a vector/list of Point_3's -- specifically, a Point_3/index pairing somehow).  I suspect there's some a generic-iterator trick applicable here (which I don't yet understand).  Thanks again kindly for your help and time.

Comment: I really don't think you can use an "iterator trick" for that, even though I'm no real expert. But you could inherit your current traits class, in which you would inherit the point_3 type in your own, which would be the same one but with an ID field.  Something like that may work.